# Storyboard Content Not Showing

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, storyboard

I'm working with storyboards for my views in a Swift app. I just created a new view controller and made it a class of StreamViewController. For some reason, no content is showing on the storyboard when I simulate the app? The only thing I've added in the storyboard is a Navigation bar.

StreamViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class StreamViewController : UIViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  }
}
```

Storyboard Settings

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does your controller load? Has it an arrow on the left side of the viewcontroller which shows that it is the initialviewcontroller?

Comment: should it be the initialviewcontroller?

Comment: Yes because otherwise, another viewcontroller will be the one you see on application-launch.

Comment: I have another controller that's the main controller to be seen on launch.

Comment: So you need to make either a segue to this viewcontroller from your initial viewcontroller, or you need to make this controller the initialviewcontroller.

Comment: Click on your StreamViewController go to Attribute Inspector then in View Controller section check IS Initial View Controller

Comment: That worked! Awesome. Can you make that an answer so I can mark it as the answer to my question?